# Logging and Metrics release plans

Tags: open-telemetry

I am using OpenTelemetry for a long time for my tracing-related solutions, but now I want to also try logging and metrics support. As I am able to see both are in development and not released yet, so are there any plans to release for a stable version?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what release is in question but generally there are specification releases and then there are releases in specific implementations of the specification (.NET, Go, Java, ...). In another dimension we have parts of the specification (e.g. API and SDK), they have their own releases and timelines.

You can see the general status on [GitHub](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/milestones) and - more succinctly - on the OpenTelemetry web [here](https://opentelemetry.io/status/).

As of now (Feb 14 2022), metrics are actually quite stable:
[image: OpenTelemetry status]